# What PAM service name does useradd use?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

The title says everything, but to show that I did my research, I will say that I spent almost half of the day yesterday trying to find the answer for that question.

I have run into one page where it was suggested that system-auth is being used by `useradd`, but except this statement I saw nothing convincing there.

Surely, I can use PAM to authenticate the given user by a program using `pam_start( "system-auth" ) ;`, but what about adding a user.

What if I wanted to use Active Directory or LDAP not only to access my Linux server, but also actively adding from that Linux server (as root) new users?

Would simple `useradd jerry` worked?
How would it know to add jerry to LDAP and not to /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow?

The best would be a reference to an article I could read rather than opinion "I think that system-auth is good" or "you should rather use the passwd service name"

Thank you in advance!
- Greg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What PAM service name does useradd use?

It doesn't use PAM to look up the system authentication service at all. The only thing it uses PAM for is to authenticate the user who's calling `useradd` (not the user account being created). And that only happens if it was compiled to use setuid and PAM.

> what about adding a user

PAM doesn't address user or group management (the misleading name of `pam_acct_mgmt` notwithstanding), only authentication.

> What if I wanted to use Active Domain

Assuming you mean Active Directory, that uses a combination of LDAP and Kerberos, but PAM doesn't work well with Kerberos.

> or LDAP

You'll have to use `ldapadd` or some other LDAP-aware tool.

> The best would be a reference to an article I could read

I can give you [source code](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow) at least. From `src/useradd.c` you can follow the call to `pw_update`, which is defined in `lib/pwio.c`, and see that the global `passwd_db` is configured with the macro `PASSWD_FILE`, which defaults in `lib/defines.h` to `/etc/passwd`. There are similar code paths connecting it to `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/gshadow`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you also for `ldapadd` function. This will not help me much for I need to have a universal method to manipulate users based on user's configuration (PAM) rather implementing specific calls. I have stumbled upon `/etc/nsswitch.conf` when playing with ldap, so maybe this is something that can help?

Comment: BTW - Thank you for the Active Domain correction. I have fixed that in my original post.

Comment: I don't think there's a commonly available open source tool to do what you're asking, but you might want to ask it is a new question.

Comment: I have noticed that `system-auth` contains `pam_unix.so`, and it's description says: "This is the standard Unix authentication module. It uses standard calls from the system's libraries to retrieve and set account information as well as authentication." The fact that it lists authentication separately indicates to me that it also is used for other things like adding users.

Comment: Thank you for the source of useradd.c. It indicates that it does write to `/etc/shadow` (via `commonio_open`,`fput`,`comminio_close`) so at least I know I can change location of the file, but indeed it cannot be used for LDAP :(. Anyway - if pam_unix.so can add users then how does it happen if not via useradd. I am confused... and searching.

Comment: Forget about what I wrote about pam_unix.so. These additional activities are *not* related to adding users. So I will end up using different method of adding users as you suggested. Thank you.